# I cannot change the text in textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I can print the values of variables (latitude, longitude, imageloc) using System.out.println() in DataOutputActivity.java, but when I try to set the text of textview with one of the above variable, the app shutdown. I have also declared the id for the textview in layout file. I cannot figure out what is wrong. There is no syntax error, only runtime error. If I remove the last two line of the onCreate() method, then there is no issue.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_ouput);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String latitude = intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_LATITUDE);
        String longitude = intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_LONGITUDE);
        String imageLoc = intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_IMAGELOC);
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        textview.setText(latitude);
        setContentView(textview);
    }
```

fragment_data_output.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.urbsalus.DataOuputActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Latitude"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="title_activity_data_ouput">DataOuputActivity</string>
    <string name="Latitude">Latitude</string>

</resources>
```

LogChat

```
07-22 17:04:18.761: D/OpenGLRenderer(15827): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-22 17:04:19.231: D/OpenGLRenderer(15827): Flushing caches (mode 2)
07-22 17:04:19.651: D/OpenGLRenderer(15827): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-22 17:04:20.201: D/memalloc(15827): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51fb1000 size:6144000 offset:4608000
07-22 17:04:20.211: D/memalloc(15827): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x525f3000 size:7680000 offset:6144000
07-22 17:04:20.321: D/CLIPBOARD(15827): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-22 17:04:20.341: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15827): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-22 17:04:30.181: D/AndroidRuntime(15827): Shutting down VM
07-22 17:04:30.181: W/dalvikvm(15827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c0da68)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.urbsalus/com.example.urbsalus.DataOuputActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at com.example.urbsalus.DataOuputActivity.onCreate(DataOuputActivity.java:30)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-22 17:04:30.191: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    ... 11 more
07-22 17:04:38.141: I/Process(15827): Sending signal. PID: 15827 SIG: 9
```

Comment: setContentView(textview) ?

Comment: Remove "setContentView(textview);" Its Not USABLE..

Comment: what does line 30 has?

Comment: post this line  at `com.example.urbsalus.DataOuputActivity.onCreate(DataOuputActivity.java:30)`

Comment: `textview.setText(latitude).tostring();` try this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove this line, it is incorrect.

```
setContentView(textview);
```

Secondly in this line

```
String latitude = intent.getStringExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_LATITUDE);
```

you are trying to get a string form the Extras in the Intent (you are not reading from your Resources file). If the value in **HomeActivity.EXTRA_LATITUDE** doesn't exists, the string will be returned as null, hence your null pointer error.

you could check against this by doing something like

```
if (latitude != null) {
    textview.setText(latitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line 30 in onCreate is textView.settext(""); you must change the

```
setContenView(R.layout.activity_data_output);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_data_output);
```

and do not call setContentView after the settext twice!!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the TextView is in the Fragment. You're mixing the content view of the Activity with the displayed Fragment, and most likely the only thing created by `setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_ouput)` is a container for the PlaceholderFragment.

You should use the template for fragments specified in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr

Answer (score 0):

You see in LogCat `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` , Check out where you didn't `new` or didn't give reference to an object

Comment: He just thinks there is a view at `R.id.outputText` even though there isn't, because if there is, it's inside the `PlaceholderFragment`.